# Get JSON object from URL with php

Tags: php, json

I have from url this

```
[{"user_id":"3932131","username":"DanielDimitrov","count300":"1677134","count100":"239025","count50":"41207","playcount":"17730","ranked_score":"1413977663","total_score":"7355146958","pp_rank":"35848","level":"95.5852","pp_raw":"1582.26","accuracy":"97.88556671142578","count_rank_ss":"42","count_rank_s":"337","count_rank_a":"120","country":"BG","events":[]}]
```

and my php is this

```
$json = file_get_contents('url');
    $obj = json_decode($json);
    echo $obj->user_id;
    echo 'Username: '.$obj['username'].'<br>';
    echo 'PP: '.(int)$obj['pp_raw'].'<br>';
    echo 'Level: '.(int)$obj['level'].'<br>';
    echo 'Play count: '.$obj['playcount'].'<br>';
```

I try to remove the brackets from the url and the code run but i get it with brackets... How can i remove them?

Comment: Which brackets? What are you attempting to do? What is the exact error you're encountering?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$json = '[{"user_id":"3932131","username":"DanielDimitrov","count300":"1677134","count100":"239025","count50":"41207","playcount":"17730","ranked_score":"1413977663","total_score":"7355146958","pp_rank":"35848","level":"95.5852","pp_raw":"1582.26","accuracy":"97.88556671142578","count_rank_ss":"42","count_rank_s":"337","count_rank_a":"120","country":"BG","events":[]}]';
    $in = array("[{", "}]");
    $out = array("{", "}");
    $obj = json_decode(str_replace($in, $out, $json));
    echo $obj->user_id;
    echo 'Username: '.$obj->username.'<br>';
    echo 'PP: '.(int)$obj->pp_raw.'<br>';
    echo 'Level: '.(int)$obj->level.'<br>';
    echo 'Play count: '.$obj->playcount.'<br>';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

`$obj` is an array with 1 element.

The short fix is, do `$obj = $obj[0]` first.

Then you can do `$obj["user_id"]` etc.